# paypal express checkout change image button

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-buttons

I am using the advanced integration procedure to integrate a paypal button, but I would like to change the default image of the button with the one that includes also the credit card logos, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<div id="paypal-button"></div>

<script>
  paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox',
    locale:'it_IT',
    payment: function(resolve, reject) {
         var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = '/make-payment';

        paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
            .then(function(data) { resolve(data.paymentID); })
            .catch(function(err) { reject(err); });
    },
    style: {
        size: 'medium',
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'rect'
    },
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        console.log("done")
   }
}, '#paypal-button'); 
</script>
```

By reading the documentation it seems that it is not possible to set an attribute to change the default paypal image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going forward, the integration requires that the button is rendered by PayPal -- this mean we can keep a consistently hi-resolution button across all devices, so the button looks sharp no matter what the display, including retina devices.

I'm part of the team that works on this button, so we can look into adding a variation which includes card logos. I think it'd be a useful addition.

https://medium.com/@bluepnume/less-is-more-reducing-thousands-of-paypal-buttons-into-a-single-iframe-using-xcomponent-d902d71d8875#.sf9jm8q4s

Comment: Yes that would be very useful. Besides that, I'd like to ask: it is allowed to use a custom button instead of the button rendered by checkout.js? In this case the button would call a server function that, after creating the payment with the paypal API, will redirect directly to the paypal checkout page using for example $this->redirect($payment->getApprovalLink());

Comment: That's an option, but not recommended. Going forward, most of our efforts and optimizations will be focused on the `paypal.Button` integration, including customizing the button for remembered users, to improve conversion and drive more sales on your site. But you do have the option of opting out and doing a redirect instead.

Comment: @bluepnume I may be misunderstanding what gcswoosh's is doing, but for the direct in browser express checkout, it's not possible to use your own button without going with the Braintree method?

Comment: @JackRothrock, going forwards, even the Braintree method will require using the standard button and using the customization options available at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/customize-button/ . Because the button is an iframe, we have plans to improve the buyer experience if they're a recognized user, and do things like automatically render the correct language for a given user.

Comment: @bluepnume I'll be honest, that's really unfortunate to hear. I get why you're going that route, but you should really consider allowing full css customization; including hover. The buttons are really ugly

Comment: Or even just allowing a transparent background with a border, would be great

Comment: Some thoughts on this: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/less-is-more-reducing-thousands-of-paypal-buttons-into-a-single-iframe-using-xcomponent-d902d71d8875#.sf9jm8q4s

Comment: Also @JackRothrock -- is there a specific button you're talking about that you don't like? Part of this effort is to really improve on that, so open to hearing more of your thoughts.

Comment: The gold just feels old. I feel like I've seen that exact button for like 5-6 years now. I can't comment on the blue as it just didn't work on my white background so i ditched it, and the grey doesn't look bad with my setup, but it doesn't, pop. Maybe a contrasting border would help. Some interaction wouldn't hurt, like get some waves when people click it or have a drop shadow or change the background color a couple pixels. It just feels old

Comment: These are all good points. Let me pass them on to our design team.

Comment: Bluepnume, are you saying that something has changed in how custom buttons are treated? I had custom images working on about 10 buttons on my donations page. I am simply trying to edit one to point to a different PayPal account and now they are broken (i.e. the image does not show). Any ideas?